# ObjectId.getTimestamp() from MongoDB .NET Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using v2.9 of the MongoDB .NET Driver and want to use the [ObjectId.getTimestamp()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/#ObjectId.getTimestamp) shell method.  Is there any way to call this from my code in C#?

I have searched the [Mongo SDK docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.9/) but have not found anything I can use.

Here is my sample model I am using with the [Microsoft docs tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace WebApi.Models
{
    public class Currency
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        // Need a CreatedAt getter that uses ObjectId.getTimestamp()

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string IsoNumeric { get; set; }
        public int MinorUnit { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public string SubUnit { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After some random keyword auto-filling in my IDE I found the ObjectId class and it has a CreationTime getter -- http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.9/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Bson_ObjectId_CreationTime.htm

In my class I added the following and it appears to work properly for what I need

```cs
        [BsonIgnore]
        public DateTime? CreatedAt => Id != null ? new ObjectId(Id).CreationTime : (DateTime?) null;
```